# How to use collate for a case sensitive search within a nested case statement?

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently running a query in which I'm looking for the case sensitive letters '%AR%' within a column. There are other words that have the letters within the name and sometimes the letters are paired with another word like "ARmart", so the only way to differentiate what I'm looking for is by case. This is the case statement I need to use it in 
`case when end_time is not null then 'completed' when status='S' or status='SR'  then 'In Progress' else 'not completed' end as completed,
case when status != 'D' then 'Error Occured' end as error,case when service like '%AR%' then 'Accounts Receivable' end as used_by`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a case sensitive version of a collation in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920584/how-to-get-a-case-sensitive-version-of-a-collation-in-sql-server)

Comment: Where is the case statement used?

Comment: After a select statement and before the from statement. There are also several unions.

Answer (score 0):

By default your `like` will return anything with `AR`. Here's an example:

```
declare @lower varchar (16), @mix varchar(16), @upper varchar(16)
set @lower = 'ddarcc'
set @mix = 'dDArcc'
set @upper = 'DDARCC'

select @lower where @lower like '%AR%'
select @mix where @mix like '%AR%'
select @upper where @upper like '%AR%'
```

To change this, COLLATE it to be case-sensitive:

```
declare @lower varchar (16), @mix varchar(16), @upper varchar(16)
set @lower = 'ddarcc'
set @mix = 'dDArcc'
set @upper = 'DDARCC'

select @lower where @lower  like '%AR%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
select @mix Latin1_General_CS_AS where @mix like '%AR%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
select @upper Latin1_General_CS_AS where @upper like '%AR%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```